# replace hyphen with a space for the text given in the div

Tags: jquery

```
<div>This-is-text-1</div>
```

Given the code line

```
var value = $('div').text();
```

I need to replave the hyphens `-` to an empty space . The output I require is " This is text 1 "How can I use the jQuery replace function here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var value = $('div').text();
$('div').text(value.replace(/\-/g, " "));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g7BU8/)

Answer (score 1):

use regex to replace all occurrences of `-`:

```
var value = $('div').text();
$('div').html(value.replace(/-/g, " "));
   //--------------------------^---^-----g is used to replace all occurrences and
   //------------------------------------" " put a space too to replace with
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4qgJy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div').text($('div').text().replace(/-/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$('div').html().replace("-"," ");
```